# Problem RestSharp - StatusCode: InternalServerError

Tags: c#, api, html-parsing, restsharp, asp.net-core-5.0

Good day!

1. Create a new project "ConsoleApp" .NET 5.0
2. I add using RestSharp; (Nuget RestSharp 106.12.0)
3. We write the following code:

```
var Client = New RESTClient ("https://emex.ru/api/search/search");
client.timeout = -1;
var Request = New RestRequest (method.get);
IRestResponse Response = Client.Execute (Request);
Console.WriteLine (response.content);
```

4. I launch the project and see a successful request with the answer.
   [ConsoleApp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Yksf.png)

5. Result: "**StatusCode: OK**, Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8, Content-Length: -1)"

***Problem:***
If you do the same in the new project Web App ASP.NET Core (MVC) .NET 5.0 - then we will always see a mistake.

1. Create a new project Web App ASP.NET CORE (MVC) .NET 5.0
2. I add using RestSharp; (Nuget RestSharp 106.12.0)
3. We write the same code:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://emex.ru/api/search/search");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

4. I launch the project and see a request error
   [Web  App ASP.NET Core (MVC)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMHTw.png)

5. Bad Result: "**StatusCode: InternalServerError**, Content-Type: , Content-Length: -1)"

What's wrong with this URL in the Web App ASP.NET CORE (MVC) .NET 5.0
Any other URL works stable!

Thanks in advance and sorry for my English!

Comment: Where did you write the code in mvc application? I mean in which file or class did you write the code ?

Comment: Tried:

1. Default HomeController> **public IACTIONRESULT INDEX()** /

2. **Created a new controller** /

3. **public JSonResult Test()** /

4. **public void Test()** /

5. **Async request**...   

It does not matter where to create. The result is always bad.